# Import Blender rig on 3Ds max

Tags: rigging, export

I've made 2 rigs on a blender:

- an indosaurus with IK/FK
- a killer whale without IK/FK

I tried importing the Killer whale to max by converting it to FBX but it didn't work.

Is there any way you can help me ?

here's the orca :[image]

and here's the indonosaurus :[image]

Comment: Have you tried exporting it to obj or any other file format instead?

Comment: @Deven importing it in obj reduces it to a few polygons. i've tried mendeling with the import settings but it doesn't change anything.